# Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to an admob banner to my application but unfortunately after doing all the steps of the Google documentation I still receive this warning in the logcat "could not find `com.google.android.gms.ads.adactivity`" and this message in the banner of the admob "Missing adActivity with `Android: configChanges` in AndroidManifest.xml" ALTHOUGH I added the `Android: configChanges` in AndroidManifest.xml

here is my manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

I really need your help

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`com.google.ads.AdActivity` is declared when using the admob sdk jar in the "libs" folder. It seems you're using admob via the google play services library so change:

`activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"`

To activity `android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"`

Also make sure you add the meta-data tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Add this activity to your manifest file

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```