# AdView - Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, admob, logcat

I just set up my app with the Google Play library method of adding adds (AdMob). When I run the emulator the add has the error message:

```
Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml
```

I located a fix at:

[Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276027/missing-adactivity-with-androidconfigchanges-in-androidmanifest-xml)

The fix stated to do the following:

> "com.google.ads.AdActivity" is declared when using the admob sdk jar in the "libs" folder. >It seems you're using admob via the google play services library so change:
>
> activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
>
> To
>
> activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
>
> Also make sure you add the meta-data tag:

I tried this and the CatLog said to change the meta tag back to:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

My LogCat:

```
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Process: biz.midl.debtcalculator, PID: 1278
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{biz.midl.debtcalculator/biz.midl.debtcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.a(Unknown Source)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.U(Unknown Source)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.a(Unknown Source)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at biz.midl.debtcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-23 14:30:27.091: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my .java:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AdView adView;

double interestRate;
double r, r1;
int nRemaining, nStarting, nDifference, originalBalance,
        outstandingBalance, originalTerm;
double minPayment, additionalPayment, newPmt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); //edited out my unitID
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here is my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

I also have my Manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="biz.midl.debtcalculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity
            android:name="biz.midl.debtcalculator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="biz.midl.debtcalculator.About"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABOUT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure you have same version of Google Play Service installed on your device and library which you are adding in your eclipse project, let me know

Comment: You're both defining a layout for the `AdMob` and also adding it programmatically. Why? Probably it's not the issue, but try removing it from the layout file and simply add it programmatically since defining it via the layout might be a great headache producer as it's tricky. If this doesn't solve the issue, could you please include in your question what steps have you followed to include the Google Play Service library?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to leave the meta-data tag as is:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Additionaly, you need to replace this tag:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

With this (as suggested in the answer you linked):

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Since you are using the Google Play Services and not the legacy AdMob SDK you need to replace the name of the activity class from `com.google.ads.AdActivity` to `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity`

Answer (score 3):

This may be part of the problem. It seems you are missing....

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in you AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only have the Google Play Services library included and not both Google Play Services and Admob SDK.

It looks like the value of @integer/google_play_services_version is zero. Are the Google Play Services resources being included in your app?

Comment: google-play-services_lib is the only library I have included. my imports are added at top

Answer (score 1):

if you are using unity you should use this.

```
 <!-- Google Mobile Ads Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the layout declaration and leaving the programmatic one worked. There were also some unrelated issues causing problems with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

From update of play service to version 22 you can go without making above change , I am pasting the code for future reference here

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

in androidmanifest.xml file with having google play service as lib. project instead to use admobsdk.jar file

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's appear to the screen  missing activity with android configchanges in Android manifestxml