# Trying to get admod to work (red box with red text comes up)

Tags: android

I followed Google's tutorial on creating a banner ad.

When the program runs a box on top of the screen comes up in red with the following text
"Missing AdActivity with Android.configChanges in AndroidManifest xml"

code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing adActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276027/missing-adactivity-with-androidconfigchanges-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the app's manifest file the following:

```
<application>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Don't forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</application>
```